# How would you securely give customers access to an Aurora RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a project that requires me to create an Aurora MySQL instance that my manager wants to be accessed by our customers. The Aurora instance will have one DB per customer. Each DB will have customer records that we will want to be read by customers using BI tools (the tool is yet to be determined). I was told that we want to let the customer decide what tool to use to sort through the data. We just want to provide a way for them to access their data in the MySQL DB.

My question is what is the most secure way to give access to this Aurora DB to our customers? Of course, we only want each costumer to access only their DB/data in the instance.

My first idea was to create one user per customer on the Aurora instance and give that user access only to their DB. I could then give the customer their username and password and white list them to allow them into this Aurora instance.

Not being an expert on this I was told that it was a very bad idea to allow direct public access to any Aurora DB. I think that shoots my first idea out the window.

What would be the best way to allow this?

Thanks for any help or advice!!

Comment: "I was told that it was a very bad idea to allow direct public access to any Aurora DB". While this is true, it also sounds like exactly what your manager is telling you to do. I'm not sure how you could really make it more secure given the requirements you are being given.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using IAM to deal with this. Set up SSL and let AWS Iam roles deal with the access. Easier to controll the user pool and permission without having to deal with it inside the db instance.

[See more here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/security_iam_service-with-iam.html)